# Permissions issues with mounting remote server into a specific folder

Tags: mount, sshfs

I'm doing the following to mount a remote server to a specific path on my server:

```
sshfs user@remoteserver.com:/backup/folder/ /home/myuser/server-backups/
```

However when I mount the server the folder permissions change (they become 700), and when I test my rsnapshot.conf file I get the following error:

```
snapshot_root /home/myuser/server-backups/ - snapshot_root exists \
         but is not readable
```

What am I doing wrong ? should I mount the remote server with another user ?

Comment: Cross-posted at [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/20621/permissions-issues-with-mounting-remote-server-into-a-specific-folder), [Unix Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5549/permissions-issues-with-mounting-remote-server-into-a-specific-folder) and [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/questions/220129/permissions-issues-with-mounting-remote-server-into-a-specific-folder). Please hyperlink your questions when you cross-post so that people can find all answers, and don't waste time posting similar answer independently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the `-o allow_root` and `-o allow_other` options to sshfs.

Answer (score 2):

On the backup server make a directory to put the backups in

`mkdir /home/patrick/backups`

On your vps

Add your user account to the fuse group

`sudo usermod -a -G fuse patrick`

Edit the `/etc/fuse.conf` file and uncomment or add the line

`user_allow_other`

make a mount point for sshfs and connect to it

`mkdir /backups`

`sshfs patrick@backup.tld:/home/patrick/backups /backups -o allow_root`

You should now have a `/backups` directory that you can use rsnapshot with on your vps.

Answer (score -2):

Set this up on Raspberry Pi (admittedly different distro) but I had the same problem with permission denied. -o allow_other added to the end of the mount call worked a treat.

Comment: Can you please give details on _how_ to do this?